# Redirect All Mail to File

Tags: php, linux, bash, unix, sendmail

Years ago, I ran across a short snippet of inline bash code that went into the php.ini file at the sendmail_path config entry. The purpose of the inline bash snippet was to redirect all mail to a file. Unfortunately, I lost the snippet. I want to use this for my development machine. Has anyone ever seen a snippet like this?

Comment: One could just invoke [`tee(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ php -d sendmail_path="cat - >> /tmp/mailfile" -r "var_dump(mail('me@localhost','foo','bar'));"
bool(true)
$ cat /tmp/mailfile 
To: me@localhost
Subject: foo
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:Command line code


bar
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works: `sendmail_path='tee -a /tmp/mail.out > /dev/null'`

Comment: I would indeed, but why duplicate the stdin stream to a stdout stream to just pipe it to dev/null if not needed?

Comment: I don't need the var_dump. Would this work?  `sendmail_path="cat - >> /tmp/mailfile"`

Comment: Yeah, the `var_dump` was just to show `mail()` still returns `true` / success.

Answer (score 1):

"cat" based one liner may create race condition when two email are send in parallel. IMHO they may be fit for low load simple test environment.

I would recommend solution based e.g. on procmail.
Procmail can use locks when delivering to mailbox file or deliver to maildir.

```
sendmail_path="/usr/bin/procmail -m /etc/procmailrcs/catch-mail.rc"
```

/etc/procmailrcs/catch-mail.rc :

```
# deliver messages to /tmp/mailfile mailbox file
DEFAULT=/tmp/mailfile
```